# Adding Certain numbers to a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

i am trying to do a small project, which requires me to cycle through one list (list y)  and append the numbers in that list to list x one by one, if the sum of x == 20, then my output will be 'okay'. so my program should pick up the number 5, but it is not. Any Help?

```
x = [5,5,5]
y = [1,2,5,6]

for number in y:
    x.append(number)
    if number + sum(x) == 20:
        print('ok')
        print(number)
        print(x)
        print(sum(x))
```

Comment: Why should it pick up the number 5 only? It will iterate through y one by one, namely starting with '1' => sum(x) is 16. then '2' => sum(x) is 18. then '5' => sum(x) is 23. The sum of x will never be 20.

Comment: basically i want it to tell me which number in list Y can be appended to list X so that the sum of list X can give me 20 (which is 5)
if i chose another number, say 17
i would want the program to tell me which number in list y can be appended to list X so that the sum will give me 17 (in that case it would be 2)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh That helped a ton
Thank You!!

Comment: -> Moved my comment to an answer, mark as correct if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You append unconditionally, meaning `x.append()` gets called for every number, not just the number that matches. Move `x.append(number)` inside the if.
Further, add a `break` inside the if, to prevent further numbers from getting added once a number was found.

```py
x = [5,5,5]
y = [1,2,5,6]

for number in y:
    if number + sum(x) == 20:
        x.append(number)
        print('ok')
        print(number)
        print(x)
        print(sum(x))
        break
```